# json_encode passing through to js file

Tags: ajax, getjson, json

bit of a newbie here.

I have the below code which gets data from a data and formats it as a json string. But how can I put this into my js to work with the code there?

PHP / Json encode

```
<?php include "db.php" ?>

<?php


echo " <br /> Currently Viewing Feedback For 13 <br />  <br />  <br />  <br /> ";



$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback");



while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

  echo "<br /> <br /> <br />";
  echo json_encode($result);
}





?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right here, you just try to encode the mysqli_result into json that's not the right thing to do..
And, don't try to put HTML into your JSON response ;)

```
<?php include "db.php"


echo " <br /> Currently Viewing Feedback For 13 <br />  <br />  <br />  <br /> ";



$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback");

$finalResult = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

  $finalResult[] = $row;

}

  echo json_encode($finalResult);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried your code and the array is showing up as {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null} Should this not be the data from the db? Sorry if i'm asking a really silly question.

Comment: Really silly question for me : Is there data in your  table ?
Try to use the mysqli_fetch_array instead of fetch_assoc

Comment: Yep got data in there. Tried the mysqli_fetch_array, no luck nothing shows up.

Comment: My bad : See the modification (json_encode($finalResult))
If it dont work try :
var_dump($result); var_dump($result->num_rows);
If the object still show null,
the problem came from the mysql_result object : it does not retrieve data from the server until it's actually required

Comment: Thanks Yeppao! Works :) Would you know how I could convert this string into a table using JS?

Comment: use jQuery.parseJSON(yourAjaxResponse);

Comment: I know im being a bit of an idiot here but what would I Ajax response be?

Comment: It depends of your system.
You can format a typical json object that your js program can interpret with differents vars for the stat, and one var for the result
Or you can return only your result with no other thing...